# Trying to Remove Wordpress Action in Plugin

Tags: wordpress, action

I have a plugin that loads Google Fonts into head of the website but I want to remove that action. Here is how they do it:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_web_font', 0 );
```

I'm trying to remove it like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_my_action', 20 );
function remove_my_action(){
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'add_web_font', 0 );
}
```

I'm not sure why the above is not removing it? I have my code placed in a plugin. Even with the priority to 0 it still does not stop the action.

Answer (score 0):

In `remove_action`, you must also include the priority that was used when the action was defined, if it isn't the default value of 10. In your case the action was added with a priority of 0, so you need to use the following:

```
function remove_my_action(){
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'add_web_font', 0 );
}
```

Ref: [Wordpress Codex: remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

> **Important**: To remove a hook, the *$function_to_remove and $priority* arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.

Comment: Thank, I've tried that way as well and it's still not removing it.

Comment: @BenJonroc Did you try changing the priority of your own `add_action`? You want to make sure it gets called *after* the original, so don't use 0 for it.

Comment: If my plugin is loading before the other plugin will that cause it not to unregister it?

Comment: @BenJonroc you should be fine if you plugin loads first, just as long as you are hooking into WP at the correct time - its the calls to `add_action` that you need to make sire are in the right sequence.

Comment: Thanks @FluffyKitten I got it  by adding my action to plugins_loaded

Comment: @BenJonroc Glad I could help! I was offline for a bit & was actually coming back to suggest using a different hook, but you found it yourself in the meantime :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @FluffyKitten for getting me thinking in the right direction. I added my action to plugins_loaded to ensure it runs after. The working code is as follows:

```
function remove_my_action(){
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'add_web_font', 0 );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_my_action', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hook in Oxygen has changed to `oxygen_enqueue_frontend_scripts`

`remove_action('oxygen_enqueue_frontend_scripts', 'add_web_font',0);`

found in File component-init.php:4344 in Version 3.9

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31431180)